# Удаление значения тега option

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Делаю скрипт онлайн записи по времени на php+javascript. При обработке html формы данные отправляются методом POST в php файл, там делается обработка... Помимо всего прочего нужно сделать так, чтобы после щелчка на кнопку удалялось значение тега `<option>`, которое было выбрано. Написал функцию и значение удаляется, однако после нажатия на кнопку форма обновляется, что приводит к тому, что форма принимает исходный вид - все значения `<option>` возвращаются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов решения: 
 1. Сохранять информацию об удалённой опции в куки и при загрузки читать этот набор куки и убирать те которые отмечены.
 2. сохранять на сервере этот набор и при генерации страницы так же ориентироваться на эту информацию

Answer (score 1):

Кроме тех способов, которые предложил [[@Чад](/users/7390/%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B4)](/users/7390/%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B4), есть еще один способ - отправлять данные в обработчик средствами Ajax. В таком случае, перезагрузка страницы происходить не будет, а значит удаленные элементы option останутся невидимыми до принудительного обновления страницы.

Comment: Да, не внимательно прочитал, думал что проблема как раз в том что после обновления страницы пользователем, всё ломается. Я бы предложил совместить оба варианта - обновление аяксом, и при перезагрузке грузить только то что надо